# How do I refresh Application metadata - URL handlers, Web browsers - after installing my own AppleScript?

Tags: safari, applescript, defaults

I'm working on an Apple Script that handles URLs. There's a command one can give which re-creates the list that Safari shows to change the default web browser.

Anyone know what this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you saved your AppleScript as application and declared that it can handle the `http` and `https` URL scheme in its `Info.plist` file, you simply need to update its modification date e.g. by running `touch "My Program.app"` in Terminal, or moving it to a different folder and back again in Finder.

Launch Services will then pick up the change automatically. You will need to restart Safari to update the browser list.

[image]

Comment: Ah hah, interesting! Yes, the system does pick up these changes. There is definitely some under-the-covers magic going on: I couldn't do a cp -pR at the command line, but DnD in Finder was fine for deploying the app.

Comment: @Dogweather Yeah, *preserving modification time* looks like a good reason for Launch Services to not check the bundle again.